# Temperature calibration for MCP9808

Tags: temperature, calibration

Reading a lot, I have found nothing about calibration for the MCP9808. I have read the datasheet and understand that the chip converts the temperature to Celsius. The given accuracy in the datsheet is typically -+0.25/0.5 Celsius. And my question to you is if you think this is enough for a normal temperature sensing application ( weather sensing,room sensing and etc.. ?) I mean how do I know how accurate or how precise the sensor is? So far, I have come forth to that a calibration isn't needed, but I think it would be a "timesaver" for everyone if someone answered this question properly and maybe open a discussion if possible.

Regards, junior Engineer

Comment: We certainly can't tell you if the specs are good enough for your application.  The sensor datasheet tells you how accurate the device is.  You think about your application, and figure out if that's good enough.  If it's not, you need to search for a more tightly specced sensor, and expect to pay more.

Comment: Why would you even quote "typical" accuracy? What happens if you get 1,000 units that don't happen to be  typical, but meet the guaranteed specifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And my question to you is if you think this is enough for a normal
>   temperature sensing application

This is what the spec says on the front page: -

Accuracy:

- ±0.25 (typical) from -40°C to +125°C
- ±0.5°C (maximum) from -20°C to 100°C
- ±1°C (maximum) from -40°C to +125°C

My personal opinion on whether this is accurate enough is immaterial.

My advice is ask yourself if this is acceptable for your application.